# Simplest way to programatically map certain keyboard's keys

Tags: keyboard, mapping, driver

Consider the following: let's say we have a multiplayer game that can be played with one keyboard by two players. Hovewer, first player's control keys are far easier to use that second player's (for example, first player uses arrow keys, when second one has to use WSAD). Important thing is that we can't change these settings in the game options menu.

I figured out the simplest way would be to plug in second keyboard and map its arrow keys as WSAD keys, so both players could use arrow keys when playing that game. But it turns out that there isn't any ready solution for that problem. I've searched for some programs and system options for key mapping, and after my research I've learned that this kind of software - one that would allow to change key mapping for certain keyboard device - is nowhere to be found.

Does that mean I'd have to write some kind of a driver for that particular keyboard I want its key mapped to another keys? I have no experience in writting device drivers of that kind, and any other solutions (including global hacks for keyboard messages, considering I'm using Windows or using programs such as KeyMapper) would work for every keyboard plugged to PC, not just desired one.

So, uhm... Is there some simpler way? I do have basic coding skills, but writting a driver for USB keyboard would be too much for me, I guess (I heard writting device drivers isn't that simple after all).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some research, I found perfect solution:
http://www.oblita.com/interception.html

This API can do some really cool things with keyboard device. Key mapping is just on of them.
Hope this helps anyone who encounters problems similiar to mine.